# Which operation came last in World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two, military, soviet-union, japan, 1940s

Which operation came last in World War 2?

I know that the Kwantung Army was defeated on the 2<sup>nd</sup> of September 1945 during the Soviet Manchurian Strategic Offensive Operation (9<sup>th</sup> of August - 2<sup>nd</sup> of September 1945), which brought about the Japanese surrender signed (once again) on the 2<sup>nd</sup> of September 1945.

Is there any official notion of which operation came last? If so, is this the one?

Comment: This question is really about when a war is over. WWII ended in both theaters with many surrenders which culminated in surrender by the central government and top command and then petered out as more or less isolated (or determined) troops surrendered. Arguably the final surrender in the Pacific war took place in the 1970s when the last Japanese soldier  still under arms finally gave up. (I don't actually argue this, but one can play with definitions to make this the *real* end of the war.)

Comment: Also it would be debatable if Magic Carpet (the repatriation of hundreds of thousands or millions of US soldiers back to USA) or the search for war criminals were part of the operations of the war.

Comment: Well, Manchurian Strategic Offensive was certainly last major ground action. However, minor battles were still ongoing in Burma and China . Of course, there was activity on air and sea .

Answer (score 1):

The Soviets and the Japanese were fighting in the Kuril Islands as late as 4 September 1945.  For a somewhat sparse description, that at least has some dates, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invasion_of_the_Kuril_Islands